# Android leveler (SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER)

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am trying to create a leveler in android, but i have seriously no idea how to do it right. The return values from the accelerometer are between 10 and -10, and i have no idea how to animate a view so i looks like a real leveler. Does anyone have some sample code i can look in to?

I have searched the whole internet but could not find any example of a leveler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sample source for one can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/androgames-sample/source/browse/#svn/Market-apps/Level/trunk).

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the sample code for the Bubble level here?

http://code.google.com/p/androgames-sample/